# app crash while taping(Two actions) two view at a time

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

In my application, I have one containerView which contains two sub-views. One sub-view contains list of buttons and the other contains a table view that based on the selection of button which in first view, the content of table view has to change.

[image]

My issue is while taping the button and content view table at same time app crashes. Please guide me to fix this issue.

Comment: What does the debugger and/or the crash report states the problem is.

Comment: Could you show the code for the action triggered by the button

Comment: Post the crash report and some code where the action called

Comment: Try to put some activity view while the data is loading after the button is taped. and at that time disable user interaction for all other views :). If you wish you can use MBProgressHUD for activity view and disable the user interaction :)

Answer (score 1):

In your case on button tap you are reloading table & simultaneosly selecting row from table. It's not consistent. If you want only action of one needs to be executed then **set exclusive touch to all subviews of your containerView**.

For all subviews do-

```
[subView setExclusiveTouch:YES];
```

Comment: Set exclusive touch to both sub-views of your containerView